# How to add labels to KineticJS shapes?

Tags: html, canvas, kineticjs

I am using KineticJs to create shapes with some text label(draggable along with the shape). There wasn't any info on the [tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-circle-tutorial/). Neither did I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324514/kineticjs-rect-filltext) a very clean approach. What's a good approach to do so? The code below only creates the shape.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="container"> </div>
        <button id="new_state">New State</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).bind("ready", function () {
    stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 600,
        height: 500
    });

    layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    $('#new_state').click(function() {
        newState();
    });

});

newState = function() {
    var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: stage.getWidth()/2,
        y: stage.getHeight()/2,
        radius: 20,
        fill: 'white',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        text: 'tet',
        draggable: true
    });
    circle.on('mouseover', function() {
        $('body').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    });

    circle.on('mouseout', function() {
        $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
    });


    layer.add(circle);
    stage.add(layer);
};
```

[JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ajmartin/e8KwC/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add both the circle and text to a group and make the group draggable.
When grouped, the objects act as one item.

```
var group = new Kinetic.Group({
    draggable: true
});
group.add(circle);
group.add(text);
```

then add the group to the layer

```
 layer.add(group);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e8KwC/1/

Comment: That's pretty much the only way to go. It's the cleanest at least. If you think about what you're trying to do: Create a shape, then a text, then treat them as one, then attach events to them. There is no one step process for that, so you have to use groups... or code your own class which extends Kinetic.Shape or Text so you can do shape and  text in one fell swoop.

Comment: Thanks for the example.  One small error is that the property on the Text object is "fill" rather than "textFill".  The default fill is white, so it doesn't appear to display on a white canvas.

Comment: There is now a labels plugin for kineticJS